# Frequent Update with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

If my application requires frequent update of the data (say every 1 min), is relying on ElasticSearch update too expensive when compared with another option like MongoDB?

Comment: Are you saying you need to update the whole index every minute, or you have a random update to one document every minute?

Comment: I need to update many random records every one minute but the record is already in the system.

Comment: Elastic search is usually not preferred in case of frequent updates. But the documents become searchable in almost real-time(~1 sec) after the update.